# How to add background image to JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, background-image, jcombobox

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126994/how-to-add-background-image-to-jtextfield) how to add background image to JComboBox properly, but didn't see answers, so i thought that i should separate these two questions...

So. How to add background image to JComboBox text field and to JComboBox popup panel properly?

UPD:
Some code for you)

Current code:

```
// ... Renderer

public class CBoxListCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

     ImagePanel panel;
     JLabel label = new JLabel();

     public CBoxListCellRenderer(Image img) {panel = new ImagePanel(img);}

     public void setImage(Image img) {panel.setImage(img);}

     @Override
     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
          label.setText(value.toString());
          panel.add(label);
          return panel;
     }
}

// ... ImagePanel

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public ImagePanel(String img) {
        setImage(img);
    }

    public void setImage(String img)
    {
        try {
            this.img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(img));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Dimension size = new Dimension(this.img.getWidth(), this.img.getHeight());
        setSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);
    }
}

// ... Colorizing arrow

class ColorArrowUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {

     public static ComboBoxUI createUI(JComponent c) {
         return new ColorArrowUI();
     }

     @Override protected JButton createArrowButton() {
          return new BasicArrowButton(
               BasicArrowButton.SOUTH,
               Color.cyan, Color.magenta,
               Color.yellow, Color.blue);
     }
}

// ... Creating object

combo_language = new JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "English", "日本語", "Русский" }));
combo_language.setBorder(null);
combo_language.setRenderer(new CBoxListCellRenderer(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/form.png")).getImage()));
combo_language.setUI(new ColorArrowUI());


// ... Putting JComboBox to JFrame
```

Comment: but didn't see answers, please I can see incl. reasonable code, works for JComboBox too

Comment: yes, but you have to play with opacity for JComponents, by default every can be transparent by setOpaque

Comment: nobody going to the pastebin (my view), edit your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @mKorbel it's okay? I'm new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a custom `ListCellRenderer`. I return a `JPanel` that has painted an image to it then added a `JLabel` that holds the value of the list object. There's room for improvement on it, but it's just an example of what you can do.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCBoxListCellRenderer {

    public TestCBoxListCellRenderer() {
        String[] list = {"Hello World 1", "Hello World 2", "Hello World 3"};
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(list);
        box.setRenderer(new CBoxListCellRenderer());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, box, "Check out this Renderer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCBoxListCellRenderer();
    }

    class BackGroundPanel extends JPanel {

        BufferedImage img = null;

        public BackGroundPanel() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(TestCBoxListCellRenderer.class.getResource("/res/leafcell.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);
        }
    }

    private class CBoxListCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        final BackGroundPanel panel = new BackGroundPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            label.setText(value.toString());
            panel.add(label);

            return panel;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

You may want to add a thin line border or do something when its selected, its up to you. Use the variables from the `getListCellRendererComponent` method to render to your liking accordingly

Comment: even in an example: **never-ever** re-create the rendering component in every getXX! Incorrect code tends to be sticky :-)

Comment: @kleopatra can you elaborate on that. I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: and don't load FileIO inside Renderer, doesn't matter if is from Java package or not, still is hard and long running FileIO, (by @kleopatra) create JPanel (final) as local variable, stop repainting for JPanel (see API)

Comment: see my comment to OP, is about Opacity (I'm think)

Comment: @peeskillet Help me please! Text doesn't show up.
Why could it be?

Text shows w/o renderer...

Comment: @user3190596 I don't know. I'm running your code and it works fin for me

Comment: @peeskillet I understood that problem is in this method:

`@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        label.setText(value.toString());
        panel.add(label);
        return panel;
}
`

If i return label - it shows text w/o image.
Any ideas? Maybe layered pane?

Comment: @user3190596 like I said, I ran the code I generated, refactoring _everyting_ in that your code above changed, and it still works for me.

Comment: @peeskillet ohh... It's my BackGround Panel realization... :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using a ListCellRenderer like described here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

Comment: Have you tested this before posting this?

Comment: Not this paricular example but i used when i had to do some similar stuff and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, so. Should i try that?

Comment: @user3190596: Yes, `CustomComboBoxDemo` is a good introductory example; update your question if you have problems.

Comment: @trashgod Ok. In example there's l&f interface. Can i customize it? For exampe to set borders and arrow color to orange?

Comment: Within limits, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008587/230513). Please edit your question to include a [*Minimal, Complete, Valid Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.